# This attribute work but id attribute not work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I will use ajax for input messages and append that message but I want scroll bottom to chat but simple document ready - scroll top function does not work

Here is the working code

```
 $(document).ready(function(event){
        $('#chatboxouter').mouseenter(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
         $(this).scrollTop(400);
        
        
      });
      });
```

But not work in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        
         $('#chatboxouter').scrollTop(400);
});
```

Here is CSS code:

```
#chatboxouter{
        position: fixed;top: 80px;height: 80vh;width: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;background-color: navy;
      }
```

here Is the html code

```
<div class="mainouter" style=" position: fixed;top: 80px;height: calc(100vh - 160px);width: 100%;
background-color: red;">


<div class="chatboxouter" id="chatboxouter">
<div class="allmessageview" style="background-color: yellow;">
  Here Php input by ajax
</div></div>


</div>
```

Comment: `$(#chatboxouter)` should be `$('#chatboxouter')`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        
         $('#chatboxouter').scrollTop(400);
});
   That also not work sir

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? If `.allmessageview` gets filled by AJAX, the call to `.scrollTop()` won't have any effect since it only happens on `$(document).ready()`, which is *before* the content loads.

Comment: but scroll top need to work after call ajax in success message but tnot work

Comment: If you want to scroll to the top after the AJAX load, you need to add the call to `.scrollTop()` to your AJAX code. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69231145/edit) to show us the relevant JS code. StackOverflow works best when you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, not just a few small pieces of your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind you can use javascript like:-

```
<script>
     document.querySelector(document).ready(function(){
         document.querySelector('#chatboxouter').scrollTop(400);
     });
</script>
```